# Как сделать сортировку контактов по алфавиту?

Tags: android, сортировка

Кто подскажет как отсортировать список контактов по алфавиту? 
Вот мой layout.

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingVertical="10dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:clipToPadding="false">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="A"
        android:textColor="#282828"
        android:textSize="30dp" />


</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/rl_contact_get_name">



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_image_contact_get_name"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name_contact_get_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:text="Меня зовут ..."
        android:textColor="#8c8c8c"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tv_time_contact_get_name"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="Время"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:format12Hour="hh:mm"
            android:textSize="12dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="23dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_more_contact_requests"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@drawable/more_green_fon"/>




</RelativeLayout>
```

`

Comment: вопрос максимально непонятный, откуда контакты, как вы их отображаете, имея на руках только разметку помочь практически нереально

Answer (score 0):

1) если у вас просто масив из строк то используйте Arrays.sort(contacts_array)

2)если у вас массив из классов то используйте этот код(здесь в роли класа Contact выступает класс"A"):

```
    public class SortTest {
public static void main (String [] av) {
    A [] arr = new A[4];
    arr[0] = new A(12,"x12");
    arr[1] = new A(16,"x16");
    arr[2] = new A(1,"x1");
    arr[3] = new A(62,"x62");
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    for (A a : arr)
        System.out.println(a);
}
}

class A implements Comparable {
private int    p;
private String s;
A() {}
A(int v, String b) {
    p = v;
    s = b;
}
@Override
public int compareTo(Object arg) {
    return p - ((A)arg).p;
}
public String toString() {
    return p+"=> "+s;
}   
}
```